# how to skip the signin step for adb 2c custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the starter pack in my application and my plan is to skip the sign in step for edit/password reset custom policies when the user is signed in already, thx

```
  <UserJourney Id="ProfileEdit">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all steps in the journey use the [SM-AAD SSO profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso).

Once you have logged in, the Sign-in Technical Profile is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

thx to James Hamil,

> you can disable the sign-in prompt for the edit and change password
> custom  policies by need to setting the keepAliveInDays parameter in
> the  relying party (RP) file that initiates the user journey.
>
> The keepAliveInDays parameter allows you to configure how long the
> "keep me signed in" (KMSI) session cookie should persist.

[how to remove signing in when using edit and update password custom policies when user is already signed in?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185225/how-to-remove-signin-when-using-edit-and-update-pa)